# Moving subviews in ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, view

So I have a scroll view with 3 other views as subviews. Using the scroll view to page between the 3 subviews which have their controllers stored in an array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    [self loadData];

    self.uiScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.uiScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.uiScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*3, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    self.uiScrollView.delegate = self;


    [self.view addSubview:self.uiScrollView];

    self.uiPhotoCollectionViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numberOfOtherViews = 3;
    int subViewOffset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCollectionViews; i++)
    {
        UIViewController* uiViewController = [[UIPhotoCollectionViewController alloc] initWithData:dataArray];
        // add offset to the view of the controller
        [self.uiScrollView addSubview:uiViewController.view];
        [self.uiViewControllers addObject:uiViewController];
        uiViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(uiViewController.view.frame,subViewOffset,0.0f);
        subViewOffset = subViewOffset + uiViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    }
```

If I later wanted to switch the view in the middle of the scroll view with the first one, how would I go about this without removing all teh scroll views subviews and replacing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible without replacing, but you can do this by swaping the objects in self.uiViewControllers array like this

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

and then after swaping the objects you can add subview by traversing the whole array.

Comment: I tried doing this. Maybe I went wrong somewhere. I just re-added them as subviews after removing and I switched the controllers in my controller array using the exchangeObjectAtIndex method.

Does that make some sense?

Comment: just exchange before adding them as subview instead of after adding them as subview

Comment: I created a seperate method to exchange them within the array of controllers, then after called another method which re-adds them as subviews to scroll view.

Is this what you mean Gangan?

Comment: Any idea why you think it would not be placing them correctly back in the scroll view. I am doing this in a for loop for every view controller I had in my array:

UIViewController* uiViewController = [self.uiViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.uiScrollView addSubview:[uiViewController view]];